# Making functions given as parameters really visible

Tags: python

A function I'm writing takes a list of functions as parameter. How can I bind the functions from the list to their names in the outer function's namespace? To clarify, this should be executable:

```
def fun1(x):
    return x+1

def fun2(x):
    return x-1

def outer(funcs, execstr):
    #???
    exec(execstr)    

outer([fun1, fun2], "print(fun1(x) + fun2(x))")
```

I think that I can find a hacky workaround with executing the code of funcs in the outer function, but it seems very wasteful. Is there a know way of doing this better?

Added: 
It's an exercise in program synthesis: I can synthesise a string with a definition of a python function F. I want to evaluate the function in the context of some wrapper function whose symbol table fills all the missing details in the code of F. The code below works fine, because fun1 and fun2 are in the outer's scope.

```
def outer():

    def fun1(x):
        return x+1

    def fun2(x):
        return x-1

    exec("print(fun1(2) + fun2(3))")

outer()
```

So, I guess that I want to add to the locals() dict of outer entries like 'fun1': ....

Edit after reading more on exec:

```
def fun1(x):
    return x+1

def fun2(x):
    return x-1

def outer(f1,f2):

    lf = {}
    lf['fun1'] = f1
    lf['fun2'] = f2    

    exec("print(fun1(2) + fun2(3))", lf)

outer(fun1, fun2)
```

Okay, I learned a bit about how it works. This is solved for me.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). Why do you want to do this? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've added more description above.

Comment: @MKnapik _I’ve added more description above_ Where?

Answer (score 0):

I think I don't fully understand the whole problem and what you intend with this, but I found it could be funny to try to do something similar.

Answering (what I believe is) your question, I think it is not possible to pass functions as parameters to "dynamically" invoke them (as far as I know in python). But you can dynamically create a program which invokes those functions.

First, create the "main" script containing the functions and variables you will use (I called it "scratch.py"). Inside that script, write a function which will write another script, according to the parameters passed to it:

```
x = 2

def fun1(x):
    return x+1

def fun2(x):
    return x-1

def outer(execstr):
    f = open('test.py', 'w')
    f.write("from scratch import *\n")
    f.write("def exec_code():\n")
    f.write("\t" + execstr + "\n")
    f.write("exec_code()\n")
    f.close()

def main():
    outer("print(fun1(x) + fun2(x))")
    import test

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This script will generate a second "dynamic" script (called test.py), which imports "main" script (scratch) to be able to use the functions and variables, and will be imported (and executed) in previous script after creating it. It will look like this:

```
from scratch import *
def exec_code():
    print(fun1(x) + fun2(x))
exec_code()
```

Output:

```
4
```

... Useless, but funny!